# Why .net process exit code not equal to stackoverflow exception exit code?

Tags: .net, process, exit-code, stack-overflow

I have .Net console application that may throw Stackoverflow exception.
Based on answer here [How does the well-known "Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException" screen appears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14590174/how-does-the-well-known-process-is-terminated-due-to-stackoverflowexception-sc) made by Hans Passant, when application failed because of StackOverflow exception it should return COR_E_STACKOVERFLOW result code.

I've looked through .net 2 source code, and here is that constant:

```
    internal const int COR_E_STACKOVERFLOW = unchecked((int)0x800703E9);
```

And the code for StackOverflow is such:

```
void DECLSPEC_NORETURN EEPolicy::HandleFatalStackOverflow(EXCEPTION_POINTERS *pExceptionInfo, BOOL fSkipDebugger)
{
  // This is fatal error.  We do not care about SO mode any more.
  // All of the code from here on out is robust to any failures in any API's that are called.
  ....

  DisplayStackOverflowException();

  TerminateProcess(GetCurrentProcess(), COR_E_STACKOVERFLOW);
  UNREACHABLE();
}
```

That equals to -2147023895. (Here is sample - http://www.dotnetfiddle.net/1rAvoF)

I start my console application from another application, and after that I check for process.ExitCode

But exit code that I've got is -1073741571, and it's not equal to stackoverflow exception code.

Why it returns different exit code?

Comment: I'd guess they changed the constant between .net versions to bring it in line with other parts of windows. `STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW` = `0xC00000FD` =  `-1073741571`

Comment: I checked StackOverflowException code in .Net 4.0 by dotPeek, and it still uses constant - "-2147023895" from _HResults internal class

Comment: I see this too now, running on Windows 8.1.  Even on .NET 3.5, the harder one to explain.  One possibility is a stack overflow triggered while handling the stack overflow.  Windows then immediately terminates the app and will use its own exception code, 0xc00000fd.  Hard to debug, got a weird EXE locking problem and gave up.

Comment: I use .Net 4.5 on Win7 x64 and got the same. 

I can rely to ntstatus.h and STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW const - http://source.winehq.org/source/include/ntstatus.h#L437 that has the that value.
But it was just interesting for me, why it rewrites it...

Thank you for the help