# System.StackOverflowException with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I created an ASP.NET project using Entity Framework 5 (DTO). When I run the project, I get an error:

[image]

Language class:

```
public class LanguageDto
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string IconCls { get; set; }

    public  ICollection<UserDto> User { get; set; }     
}
```

Error :

```
{Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state.}
```

Comment: Somewhere there is a method calling itself, possibly in the call statck of Projects() method. If you inspect the call stack usually you can find it.

Comment: Show your code and exception as a text, not as an image.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206820/how-do-i-prevent-and-or-handle-a-stackoverflowexception

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflowexception+c%23?sort=votes&pageSize=50

Comment: i added the text error

Comment: Are you using AutoMapper (and the Queryable extensions)?

Comment: yeas i use AutoMapper to make relationship between Context Class and Dto Object !

Comment: Because the failing 'line of code' is invoking a few different libraries, you should post more details.  I added the tag for `AutoMapper` to your post.  You should consider showing the Mapping definition for this entity/DTO -- of particular interest is how you have handled the `User` collection.