# HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions not work for StackOverflow exception

Tags: c#, .net

From my practice, HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions not works for StackOverflow exception but OK for AccessViolationException.

AccessViolationException from [this post](http://dailydotnettips.com/2013/09/23/corruptedstateexceptions-in-net-a-way-to-handle/) which is caught:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Wtf();
    }

    [SecurityCritical]
    [HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]
    private static void Wtf()
    {
        try
        {
            IntPtr ptr = new IntPtr(1000);
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(1000, ptr, true);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

StackOverflow exception written by myself, which catch nothing.

```
public class Test
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Wtf();
    }

    [SecurityCritical]
    [HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]
    private static void Wtf()
    {
        try
        {
            F();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }
    }

    private static void F()
    {
        F();
    }
}
```

Could someone explain this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`StackOverflowException` is not considered a Corrupted State Exception by .NET so it can't be caught in this fashion.  See [How do I prevent and/or handle a StackOverflowException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206820/how-do-i-prevent-and-or-handle-a-stackoverflowexception) for some other answers on how to do it instead.

Comment: I know that is hard to catch Stackoverflow. So I am consodering start a child process and monitor it. But in practice, I don't know which information indicate a process is throwing Stackoverflow. Any ideas?