# How can we handle the stackoverflow exception C#

Tags: c#, umbraco

I am writing C# on Umbraco CMS, then Microsoft Visual Studio detects that I should handle the stackoverflow error on

```
var umbracoHelper = new Umbraco.Web.UmbracoHelper(Umbraco.Web.UmbracoContext.Current);
Image = umbracoHelper.Media(imageId).GetCropUrl("umbracoFile", "image");
```

How I can handle this issue?
You can see the full code on this link.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6cMfQEoDEfwdnczSDRJakJIMzA

Umbraco version 7.2.8

Tool: Microsoft Visual Studio 2013

Comment: What is `Image`? Is it a property? Show us the declaration.

Comment: debugger may not always tell you where exactly  the problem is. because its hard to detect this problem. do you use recursion call?

Comment: if it's an `StackOverflowException` then you cannot catch/handle it ... it's one of those special *panic* exceptions ;)

Comment: You came to right place if you'd like to deal with `StackOverflow` exception ;) but we need more info

Comment: " Microsoft Visual Studio detects that I should handle the stackoverflow error": Does that mean you encounter one when you run the program? A stack overflow is nothing to handle but something to avoid. It usually happens because a function calls itself, directly or indirectly.

Comment: You can't "handle" a stack overflow, you must fix the bug instead.  The location where the exception is raised is rarely the exact location of the bug.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I prevent and/or handle a StackOverflowException?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206820/how-do-i-prevent-and-or-handle-a-stackoverflowexception)

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I have pasted the link of full code.

Comment: @Fabjan I have put the link of full code

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the necessary reputation to be able to comment on your original question hence this "answer" - so I apologise in advance.

There's nothing in your code example that would throw `StackOverflowException` around the lines you've indicated, so you need to look deeper.  You might possibly get a NullReferenceException on the GetCropUrl() extension method though as you haven't tested to make sure the meda item returns a valid object.

So everyone else doesn't have to download it - here's your code snippet (minus the usings/namespace):

```
public class Case
{
    public Case(IPublishedContent content) 
    {
        Id = content.Id;
        Description = content.GetPropertyValue<string>("description");
        Title = content.GetPropertyValue<string>("title");

        //image
        string image = content.GetPropertyValue<string>("image");            
        int imageId = 0;
        int.TryParse(image, out imageId);
        if (imageId != 0)
        {

                var umbracoHelper = new Umbraco.Web.UmbracoHelper(Umbraco.Web.UmbracoContext.Current);
                Image = umbracoHelper.Media(imageId).GetCropUrl("umbracoFile", "image");          
        }



        //Team
        string teamID = content.GetPropertyValue<string>("teamMember");
        Team = DAL.GetTeamProperties(teamID);
    }

    public Case() { }
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string Title { get; set; }            
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public List<Team> Team { get; set; }
}
```

It's more likely that your problem lies here rather than the code extracting the Image Url:

```
Team = DAL.GetTeamProperties(teamID);
```

However more information is needed - can you post the actual stack trace of the exception?