# System.StackOverFlowException error in published code

Tags: c#, .net

I am using VS 2010. I did changes in the code to log the application exceptions. In visual studio, when I debug, I am able to log all the exceptions in the folder allotted for that. But I'm not able to log the exceptions when I publish my application. (`System.StackOverFlowException` occurred in `mscorlib.dll`) This is the error I'm getting from the published application when I'm getting an exception and I'm not able to log any application related exceptions.

Comment: Why do you get the exception in the first place? Can't you debug it locally, fix the issue and then publish the fixed application?

Comment: First, you should do everything in your power to be able to log errors in the production environment, but in case it is really impossible, you can find your exception details in Windows Event Viewer most of the time

Comment: Please go over the [question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and then [edit] your question accordingly. An [mcve] would help because at the moment you rely on our guessing abilities

Comment: The type `System.StackOverFlowException` does not exist in mscorlib. I assume you meant `System.StackOverflowException` (note the casing). While being pedantic, that underlines the issue that you should provide actual code that exhibits the issue you see.

Comment: This old entry might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206820/how-do-i-prevent-and-or-handle-a-stackoverflowexception

Answer (score 0):

You cannot catch a `System.StackOverFlowException`. Unless you are throw it yourself or your application runs within a debugger or other host process.

You must use a debugger to capture the exception. If the exception doesn't occur in your test setup, you should get the data the 'user' is using.

Comment: I think it was downvoted because the original answer was more like a comment.