# Render partial view or view from controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I'm trying to render from controller either PartialView or View depending on condition coming from outside. Web-site fails on posting data with StackOverflowException.

Controller code:

```
    public ActionResult Login(bool partial = false)
    {
        if (partial)
        {
            ViewBag.Partial = true;
            return PartialView();
        }
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(UserViewModel userViewModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View(userViewModel);
        // some authrorization staff
    }
```

Login.cshtml:

```
    @using SK.DDP.ImageGallery.Helpers
    @model SK.DDP.ViewModels.UserViewModel

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Login";
        if (ViewBag.Partial != null)
        {
            Layout = string.Empty;
        }
    }

    @*Some form staff*@
```

AuthorizationInfo.cshtml:

```
    @{
        Layout = string.Empty;
    }

    @{ Html.RenderAction("Login", "Authorization"); }
```

Template:

```
    @*Some dif for form requested by menu*@
    @{ Html.RenderAction("AuthorizationInfo", "Authorization"); }
```

I have a web-site with login page and login popup window appearing when user clicks on menu, so i wanted to reuse the same action of controller and code and app is continuing to fail with stackoverflow exception.

Thanks.

Comment: How is  `AuthorizationInfo.cshtml` and Template related to the question? And you do not need `if (ViewBag.Partial != null)` in the view (your returning a PartialView which will not use a layout)

Comment: You don't need to  set the Layout = string.Empty  if the returned actionresult was partial, can you confirm this?

Comment: Stack overflow exception ? Look for some recursive calls. May be a action method keep calling it self ?

Comment: Since `StackOverflowException` cannot be catched, try to set breakpoints on any suspected code lines, especially on loops, recursions or methods that consume large amount of memory. Refer to this post for mitigating/preventing SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206820/how-do-i-prevent-and-or-handle-a-stackoverflowexception

Answer (score 0):

Seems its a bug in a Razor engine.

I workarounded it.

AuthorizationInfo.cshtml

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("LoginPartial"); }
```

AuthorizationController.cs

```
public ActionResult Login()
{
    return View();
}

public ActionResult LoginPartial()
{
    ViewBag.Partial = true;
    return PartialView("Login");
}
```

Now Post of forms does not generate overflows with templates applied recursively.

Comment: There is no bug in the 'Razor engine'!