# MainWindow() forcing static, but I need to call non-static parameters (C#)

Tags: c#

I am building a file watcher that loads data from a file that is dropped to a specified location in SQL. All my code is fine, except the passing of variables typed in TextBoxes in the UI to another class outside of MainWindow.

First I initialize a FileWatcher:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    FileWatch.FileWatcherLoad();
}
```

Which calls the file watcher to initialize:

```
public static void FileWatcherLoad()
{
    FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
    watcher.Path = //some path;
    watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
    watcher.Filter = "*.*";
    watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
    watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}
```

This issue is arising because the MainWindow is forcing me to declare FileWatcherLoad as a static type. When I remove the static type from File WatcherLoad() I get error:

```
an object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property 'FileWatch.FileWatcherLoad()'
```

Note that FileWatcherLoad() is in another class, FileWatch, which is a child class of MainWindow.

This is an issue for me because I wish to use user-entered data in a textbox in my UI, but this is NON STATIC, and is therefore causing a problem when I declare everything else static.

Comment: You need to create an instance of FileWatch and hold it in a variable in your window.  You don't seem to understand the concept of static vs. instance, and how garbage collection and variable scope works.  I'd strongly suggest you grab a copy of CLR Via C# and read it.  It won't take too long, and you'll be 1000% better off.

Comment: Coming from Visual Basic, aren't you? There's no default instance in C# - if you want an instance of something, you need to create it and store the reference somewhere.

Comment: Your example is confusing to read, as you posted the static version of FileWatch.

Comment: Declare a field in your mainform like: `private FileWatch fileWatch = new FileWatch();`. Then use `fileWatch.FileWatcherLoad();` in the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `FileWatch.FileWatcherLoad()` you tell the compiler that you want to call a static method. If you want to call a non static method you need to call the method on an object.

If you want to call the method on the current object you can either call `this.FileWatcherLoad()` or just `FileWatcherLoad()`.

If the method isn't in the same class as the one you are calling the method from you need to initialise an object first.

This can be done by using the `new` keyword.

```
var fileWatch = new FileWatch();
fileWatch.FileWatcherLoad();
```

Comment: This does work (removes the reference issue) but it causes another error. The InitializeComponent() now breaks with System.StackOverFlowException

Comment: @DanG A `StackOverflowException` mostly means that you have infinite recursion (example => an method calling itself forever). Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206820/how-do-i-prevent-and-or-handle-a-stackoverflowexception) link helps you resolve the issue. If not I suggest you ask a new question.

Comment: It's weird because if I leave it as static, then it calls it fine and the filewatcher works perfectly. Something about declaring the variable breaks it. I am pretty new to all this so I am not surprised I've broken it

Comment: @DanG It can't be about the signature of the method. I would step through you code. I should be easy to spot the place which keeps looping. If you the only thing you have added else is `new FileWatch` it must be something with this class.

Comment: It seemed to do with the fact that FileWatch was a child class of MainWindow - when I removed this it now works. Thanks

Comment: @DanG Hm interessting. And no problem

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do something like:

```
FileWatch myWatch=new FileWatch();
```

Then call your methods etc...

Answer (score 0):

That's cause the way you are calling it which the invocation way of `static` member function. If you want that method to be instance method then create an instance and call it like

```
FileWatch watcher = new FileWatch();
watcher.FileWatcherLoad();
```

(or) just `new FileWatch().FileWatcherLoad()`

Now you can declare your method to be `non-static` one

```
public void FileWatcherLoad()
    {
        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        watcher.Path = //some path;
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
        watcher.Filter = "*.*";
        watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }
```