# Why is there a System.StackOverflowException when I have published my web app to IIS and deployed it on another device?

Tags: .net, iis, stack-overflow

I have published my web app on IIS and it works fine. However, even if the first page works fine, as I needed to login with database, it took awhile and prompted an error saying :

> An unhandled Microsoft .NET Framework exception occurred in w3wp.exe [10060].

And as I clicked in it says:

> System.StackOverflowException: 'Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown.'

Does anyone have this problem?

Comment: It is far from trivial to answer such. You have to follow step by step guides to collect the necessary information and then might come across the solution https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tess/2008/03/31/net-case-study-stackoverflow-exception-when-using-a-complex-rowfilter/. If you are not capable of such, open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I prevent and/or handle a StackOverflowException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206820/how-do-i-prevent-and-or-handle-a-stackoverflowexception)