# exception handling in c#

Tags: c#, exception

i want to know do finally block still execute in exception handling  even if there is no matching catch block for the try block and if not then what happens?
Also i want to now system exception and application difference

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you do not need a `catch` block at all.  The `finally` block always executes.

As to the difference between `System.Exception` and `System.ApplicationException`: `Exception` is the base class for all exceptions; `ApplicationException` should be used when a non-fatal application error occurs.  See the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.applicationexception.aspx).

Also see [best practices for handling exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/seyhszts.aspx).

Comment: you mean after running the finally block the exception will be thrown and the program will terminate? (when there is no matching catch block)

Comment: Well, yes and no.  The exception will be thrown, but there could be another try-catch block surrounding the call to this one, in which case the higher level try-catch will catch this exception.

Comment: As an aside, don't use `ApplicationException`. It is deprecated. Use an appropriate exception derived from System.Exception (or derive your own) instead.

Answer (score 4):

As others mentioned `finally` will run even if there is no `catch` block. This supports Java's *try finally* pattern (which can be achieved using `IDisposable` and `using`).

One *exception* <sub>(see what I did there?)</sub> is when a `StackOverflowException` is thrown in which case the `finally` block [will **not** run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107735/stackoverflowexception-in-net) (nor would a `catch` if one were present).

The `finally` block runs after the `try` block completes (either cleanly or by throwing an exception) as you would expect from its location in the code.

Comment: P.S. I like the way the 2 Israelis answering this question are both pictured carrying a child in a backpack.  (You can't see that so well in my pic, but that's what it is...) ;)

Comment: what happens it exception arise in catch block...still the finally will execute?

Comment: also i want to know one thing if i write try block then is it compulsory to write catch block?

Comment: @Novice, no it is not, you have to have _either_ a `catch` _or_ a `finally` or **both**.

Comment: @Novice, if an exception escapes the `catch` block the (outer) `finally` block is still run.