# Asynchronous .NET Exceptions

Tags: .net, exception, clr

I have got a problem with a .NET application.
It terminates without throwing any exception. If I start it in debug mode in my visual studio, the debugging terminates also without any error message.

I have found the post [StackOverflowException in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107735/stackoverflowexception-in-net/108035#108035) which describes that this behaviour occurs when the CLR throws one the following exceptions:
- ThreadAbortException
- OutOfMemoryException
- StackOverflowException

But how can I determine which of these exception was thrown in my case?
Is it possible to log the exception and maybe to get a stack trace or the type of the exeption at least?

I have tried to write a second application, which starts the other app in a separate process. With this approach, I could detect when the process terminated, but the only information I could get in this way was the exit code -532459699. Does anyone know what that means?

Comment: seems COM+ related - see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/b9328870-9ecf-4c91-9880-cfe9c577de7d/

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `Visual Studio -> Debug -> Exceptions -> CLR Exceptions`

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure Visual Studio debugger to catch all thrown exceptions?
If not go to Debug/Exceptions... and check the box under the thrown column next to Common Language Runtime Exceptions

Answer (score 0):

Handle the domain exceptions at the main on the program:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += OnCurrentDomain_UnhandledException;

//Add these too if you are in windows forms application
Application.ThreadException += OnApplication_ThreadException;

Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);
```

Then if exception thrown just log it, and you can also restart your program from here without needing for another application to watch your process.

```
private static void OnCurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
#if DEBUG
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();//we will break here if we are in debug mode.
#endif//DEBUG

    LogException(e);
    RestartTheApplication();    
}
```